# How to add Trailing Button from ImagePicker in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I need an Add button to add the ability to edit images to my project.

I added a `NavigationView` but the UI doesn't draw as I want it to.
[image]

I want the Add button to go down like my picture.
Can you help me out?

Here's the relevant part of my code.

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                HStack(alignment: .top) {
                    Button {
                        vm.imagePickerPresented.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        let image = vm.profileImage == nil ? Image(systemName: "photo.circle") : vm.profileImage ?? Image(systemName: "photo.circle")
                            image
                                .resizable()
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                .scaledToFill()
                                .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
                                .clipShape(Rectangle())
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: $vm.imagePickerPresented) {
                        NavigationView {
                            VStack {
                                ImagePicker(image: $vm.selectedImage)
                                    .toolbar {
                                        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                                            Button {
                                                vm.cropperShown.toggle()
                                            } label: {
                                                Text("Add")
                                                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                                            }
                                            .sheet(isPresented: $vm.cropperShown, onDismiss: vm.loadImage){
                                                ImageCroppingView(shown: $vm.cropperShown,
                                                                  shownPicker: $vm.imagePickerPresented,
                                                                  image: vm.selectedImage!,
                                                                  croppedImage: $vm.croppedImage)
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        let parent: ImagePicker
        
        init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            guard let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else { return }
            self.parent.image = image
        }
    }
}
```

Do I need to add something in ImagePicker?

Comment: You're targeting single selection, so when the user taps on a picture it'll be automatically selected. If you want the add button, you need to make it multiple selections.

Answer (score 0):

In `makeUIViewController` you need to make just a standard `UIViewController` and then in `updateUIViewController` you need to use that to present or dismiss a `UIImagePickerController` depending on a boolean `isPresented`. Then you can remove your `NavigationView` because the picker already has it's own.

Also `Coordinator(self)` is a mistake because self will be out of date when this struct is re-init by its parent View's body.

By the way, have you tried SwiftUI's [`.photosPicker`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/photospicker(ispresented:selection:matching:preferreditemencoding:)/) modifier that does all this for you?

Comment: I didn't know there was such a thing as `.photosPicker.`
Thank you